# While creating executable using Python2.7 and cx_Freeze, I am getting the following error related toPython.Runtime.dll"

Tags: python, .net, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, python.net

> error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\clr\Python.Runtime.dll

**code for setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup( name = "Severity_Insertion.py",
       version = "2.7",
       description = "Executable of serirty",
       executables = [Executable("Severity_Insertion.py",base = "Win32GUI")]
     )
```

**code for hooks.py which is related to my error**

```
def load_clr(finder, module):
"""the pythonnet package (imported as 'clr') needs Python.Runtime.dll
in runtime"""
module_dir = os.path.dirname(module.file)
dllname = 'Python.Runtime.dll'
finder.IncludeFiles(os.path.join(module_dir, dllname), dllname)


def load_sqlite3(finder, module):
"""In Windows, the sqlite3 module requires an additional dll sqlite3.dll to
   be present in the build directory."""
if sys.platform == "win32":
    dll_name = "sqlite3.dll"
    dll_path = os.path.join(_get_base_prefix(), "DLLs", dll_name)
    finder.IncludeFiles(dll_path, os.path.join("lib", dll_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`finder.IncludeFiles(os.path.join(module_dir, dllname), dllname)`

should be:

`finder.IncludeFiles(dllname, dllname)`

Because `pythonnet` files `Python.Runtime.dll` and `clr.pyd` are located directly under `site-packages`.